# Why is this extension of composite fields a Galois extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $k$ be a finite field and let $L/k$ be a a finitely generated field extension. Furthermore, let $K$ be a finite Galois extension of $L$ and let $k^\prime$ denote a finite intermediate field $k\subset k^\prime\subset K$ which is algebraically closed in $K$. 
Here comes my question: Why is the extension of the composite fields $K\cdot k^\prime/L\cdot k^\prime$ a finite Galois extension?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Am I missing something here? It seems that $K\cdot k'=K$ (as $k'\subset K$) and $L\cdot k'$ ist just an intermediate field of $K/L$, so the claim should follow from the fact that if $K/L$ is Galois and $F$ is an intermediate field, then $K/F$ is again Galois.

Comment: Thank you I think you`re completely right. That was fast help thank you!

Comment: You meant $k'\subset \overline{L}$. Then $Kk'/Lk'$ is Galois because $K$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial $f\in L[x]$ and $Kk'$ is the splitting field of the same polynomial seen as $\in Lk'[x]$.